# Intercept file access on a network share in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, networking

I am looking for a way to possibly intercept the point that a file is being accessed on a network share.  Specifically before it is determined whether the user has access to the file or not.  The goal will be to grant access to that file if the file request is coming from a specific process and that user currently does not have access.  I would love a VB.NET solution, but any solution or even just ideas to go down would be wonderfully helpful!  I have been down the impersonation road, but this solution will not work for us.

Comment: And overriding domain security is a good thing how? Sound nefarious to me.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do it.  We have windows forms application that currently does a lot of processing of files that exist on a network share.  Currently in order to do read/write type things within the application all users of the application are granted read/write access to the file share.  For security reasons we would like to revoke this access, but still allow file manipulation to occur via the application.  That is why I thought if possible I could temporarily grant access if they came from the application and then revoke that access once they close out.

Comment: So what problems are you having with impersonation?  Why can't you set up the app to impersonate an account that has the required access?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with using FTP when accessing the secure file share.